# Ghidra: Automagically set Bytes to Unicode / CString

Tags: assembly, unicode, reverse-engineering, binaryfiles, ghidra

I have a Ghidra question for you. I am disecting an executable binary and I am noticing a TON of data types that are clearly Unicode in the "Listing" Pane but are showing up as unknown Bytes.

I am aware that I can click on the first address and then select "Data" > "TerminatedUnicode" but there are hundreds of these bytes that need to be converted to Unicode.

Is there an automated way to perform this tedious task?

[image: Data in Byte Format instead of Unicode]

[image: Manually casting individual Byte Data Types to Unicode]

Answer (score 4):

That should just be a fairly simple script, basically just `createUnicodeString(Address)` and `getUndefinedDataAfter(Address)` in a loop. The tricky part is deciding when to actually stop, but if you know when this memory range ends, that's just a simple additional check. Handling padding/alignment will be another slight pitfall, but it should be enough to repeat `getUndefinedDataAfter` until the current address isn't a null byte

Comment: Interesting. I've give it a shot! I'll "accept" the answer once I get a good a half-decent script written up.